# Predict a alphanumeric value

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

is it possible to predict a alphanumeric value by using ml.net (or any other ML-Framework)?

For example: i got a large list of alphanumeric codes like: "245ab67k"

Is it possible to resolve the method of how those codes got generated or is it possible to use ML.NET (or any other ML-Framework) to predict a possible alphanumeric code.

Appreciate your help!